# GTM JavaScript Compiler Error

Tags: google-tag-manager, json-ld

thanks for your attention, I'm not tech guy, so please be patient.

I use JavaScript to apply dynamic variables in my JSON-LD code for SEO (Structured Data) purposes. I faced with the problem that each time when I'm trying to Preview or Submit tags, receive this error:

> Validate Container
>
> The container has the following errors:
>
> JavaScript Compiler
>
> > Error Product - Apple Schema
> >     **Error at line 36, character 9: Parse error. '}' expected**

Here is my code:

```
    <script>
    (function(){
    var data = { 
        "@context": "http://schema.org/",
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": {{SCH Product - Device_Name}} {{SCH Device Memory}},
        "image": {{SCH Product - Device_Img}},
        "description": {{SCHEMA - Page Description}},
        "brand": {
            "@type": "Thing",
            "name": "Apple"
            },
                "aggregateRating": {
                "@type": "AggregateRating",
                "ratingValue": "4.4",
                "ratingCount": "89"
                },
                    "offers": {
                    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
                    "lowPrice": "100",
                    "highPrice": "420",
                    "priceCurrency": "USD",
                    "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/UsedCondition",
                    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
                    "seller": {
                        "@type": "Organization",
                        "name": "Ciclii"
                        }
                    }
                }
    var script = document.creatingElement('script');
    script.type = "apllication/ld+json";
    script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
    document.getElementsByTag('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    })(document)
     </script>
```

I used this article as the source:

https://moz.com/blog/using-google-tag-manager-to-dynamically-generate-schema-org-json-ld-tags

Please, share your thoughts or any advices, would highly appreciate it! - thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in this line

```
"name": {{SCH Product - Device_Name}} {{SCH Device Memory}},
```

Correct way is:

```
"name": "{{SCH Product - Device_Name}} {{SCH Device Memory}}",
```

And you forgot one `;`

Working code is:

```
  <script>
(function(){
var data = { 
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "{{SCH Product - Device_Name}} {{SCH Device Memory}}",
    "image": {{SCH Product - Device_Img}},
    "description": {{SCHEMA - Page Description}},
    "brand": {
        "@type": "Thing",
        "name": "Apple"
        },
            "aggregateRating": {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
            "ratingValue": "4.4",
            "ratingCount": "89"
            },
                "offers": {
                "@type": "AggregateOffer",
                "lowPrice": "100",
                "highPrice": "420",
                "priceCurrency": "USD",
                "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/UsedCondition",
                "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
                "seller": {
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "Ciclii"
                    }
                }
            };
var script = document.creatingElement('script');
script.type = "apllication/ld+json";
script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
document.getElementsByTag('head')[0].appendChild(script);
})(document)
 </script>
```

Why is it happening?

If you will use only your varriable without quotes `{{SCH Product - Device_Name}`, GTM will compile it to something like that `"name": google_tag_manager["GTM-XXXXXX"].macro('gtmX') google_tag_manager["GTM-XXXXXX"].macro('gtmX')`. And this construction is not valid JS

But if you will place variable inside quotes, it will execute this variable and will render as `"name": "string1 string2"`

Comment: Maybe explain why, or they will wonder why the next line has a problem, and the one after that...

Comment: @Victor Thank you a lot of, now code really works. Also, maybe you have any thought about this: http://prntscr.com/fi8bfd. Seems that GTM mixing the links since I sure that the initially I extract another value: http://prntscr.com/fi8bvo